# Ternary operators using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, conditional-operator

I am trying to create a form with 4 possible values (type: radio button). I want to choose one and then save its value in a .txt file.

This is part of my code:

```
"Booster: " + ($("#tipoBooster").is(":checked")?"block I":"dark knight":"f1b":"custom")`
```

When I execute it, it returns `uncaught syntax error unexpected token ":"`.

How can I modify it? Can you also link some online examples?

My idea is:
I have my form with these radio buttons:

```
O block I   O dark knight   O f1b   O custom
```

If I select one, I want to write `"Booster:   *selected one* "` as my output (a string).

What do you suggest?

Comment: Ternary operator chooses an output between two (`true` on the left of ":" and `false` on its right) why do you have four options?

Comment: I added an example... I need to choose between those four, otherwise the code will not be good for what I want to do

Comment: It's a _ternary_ operator though, not a quinary operator... ^^

Answer (score 2):

You should add an event listener on `"change"` on all of the `input[type=radio]` element that are involved in the decision

The listener will be fired each time an input is checked. It will not be fired when a radio is being unchecked because another one is checked, so the execution of the listener is assured to run once only each `"change"`.

In the event listener you can check the `event.target.value` property to get which radio button was checked and then you can manipulate the DOM as you want.

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ugm8Lya2/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operators can only have one else following the `:`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

You'll need to break it up into multiple ternary expressions if you want it in one line, but I'm not sure this is what you're looking for..

```
const isChecked = $("#tipoBooster").is(":checked");
const text = "Booster: " + (isChecked ? "block I" : (mySecondCondition ? "dark knight" : (myThirdCondition ? "f1b" : "custom")))
```

That said, I'm not 100% certain how you want to apply this to building a radio group, but here's some good documentation on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% what you're trying to do but if I understand correctly you could do something like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="tipoBooster" value="block I">
  <label>block I</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tipoBooster" value="dark knight">
  <label>dark knight</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="tipoBooster" value="f1b">
  <label>f1b</label>
  <div id="showStr"></div>
</div>

 var divelm = $('#showStr');
 $("input[name='tipoBooster']").on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    divelm.text('Booster: ' + $(this).val());
  }
 });
```

If you'd like to condense it a bit you could do something like this using && to only run the statement on the right if the left is true:

```
var divelm = $('#showStr');
 $("input[name='tipoBooster']").on('change', function() {
    $(this).is(':checked') && divelm.text('Booster: ' + $(this).val());
 });
```